# Use nvidia GPU in virtualbox VM

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, nvidia

Using VirtualBox, I set up new virtual machine with Windows 10. Now I want to run my application inside it. The problem is that it requires GPU to be run properly. Is there a way to configure the virtual machine to use the host'a GPU?